# Can't Upload Image with Axios Vue 3

Tags: axios, vuejs3

I want to upload image by Vue 3 and Axios with state. But error is: array to string. I don't know what to do know. Please help me. Thank so much.

HTML:

```
    <input
      type='file'
      class="hidden"
      name="avatar"
      id="avatar"
      @change="updatePreview"
      style="display: none;"
    />
```

Define State

```
const state = reactive({
  user: {},
  updateMovie: {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    image: '',
   }
```

Take file image:

```js
function updatePreview(e) {
      if (e.target.files.length === 0) {
        return
      }
      console.log(e)
      imageFile.value = e.target.files[0]

      state.updateMovie.image = e.target.files[0]
    }
    
const submitModal = (type) => {
  if (type === 'edit') {

  const form = {
    image: state.updateMovie.image,
  }
  const id = state.updateMovie.id
  console.log("form: ", form)
  console.log(typeof form.image)
  axios.post(`movie/update/${id}`, form)
    .then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
    const data = res.data.data.movie
      })
     }
   })
  }
}
```

That's all. Now i don't know what to do to send data to axios.

Comment: What's the actual error message? `array to string` does not seem like a real error.

Comment: what is your exact question? and exact error message?